# JSON Array key on an index value

Tags: java

I have two json response that are like so:

```
{
  "test": [
    {
      "value": "abc"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is a different response

```
{
  "test2": [
    {
      "value": "abc"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have this line of code to grab an object from an array:

```
httpResponse.getBody()
    .getObject()
    .getJSONArray("test")
    .getJSONObject(0)
    .get("value")
    .toString();
```

I have another one which is exactly the same but the DTD it's looking at is different:

```
httpResponse.getBody()
    .getObject()
    .getJSONArray("test2")
    .getJSONObject(0)
    .get("value")
    .toString();
```

Instead of having two lines of code, one for each jsonArray key, I want a dynamic one where it simply selects the initial DTD value and then goes in and retrieve the value. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just make a method inside your class to help you with this?

```
String extractValue(HttpResponse httpResponse, String key) {
    return httpResponse.getBody()
       .getObject()
       .getJSONArray(key)
       .getJSONObject(0)
       .get("value")
       .toString();
}
```